# how to efficiently generate all possible three words in a string in java?

Tags: java

If I have as array of string like

```
string[] word = {"a", "good", "boy", "lives, here"}
```

how can we get all possible three pair words like :

```
("a", "good", "boy")
("a", "good", "lives")
("a", "lives", "here")
("good", "boy", "lives")
("good", "lives", "here")
("boy","lives", "here")
```

Currently, I am doing employing three loops

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length - 2; i++) {
     for (int j = i+1; j < word.length - 1; j++) {
          for (int k = j+1; k < word.length ; k++) {
          ....
          .....
```

How can it be done more efficiently?

Comment: What makes you think this isn't efficient already? You're generating each possible combination exactly once ...

Comment: You need the permutation of all the elements of the array. You can see http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/ This is about permutations of string, similar code you can have for elements of array and yes Your code as mentioned in another code does well too :)

Comment: What if we are processing a large text documents instead of just of this one string array? I was thinking of finding a more efficient way of handling large amount of text lines, like say 20K lines of text and finding all possible three words in each line.

Answer (score 1):

A great deal here depends on what you mean by "efficiently".

For the moment, I'm going to assume that part of what you mean is that producing every combination of 3 words out of 4 inputs is just an example, and you might (for example) need to be able to produce every combination of 4 words out of 5 inputs, or perhaps 8 out of 10, or whatever--and you'd rather not completely rewrite the code every time the number of input words and/or words in each result changes.

In that case, we can think of "produce every combination" as a matter of counting. Your nested loops are basically just counting up from 0 to some limit for each of some number of digits. When each one reaches its limit, it rolls over to zero, and the next digit increments by one. That's pretty much just normal counting. Normally, we count in base 10, so the numbers go from 0 to 9, then roll over to 0, and the next digit increments. In this case, we just want to set an arbitrary limit on where they roll over (4, in the case above).

Doing that means we're changing the base of the number. Base 10 goes from 0 to 9. Base 8 goes from 0 to 7, and so on (i.e., it's always 0 to base-1).

So, for the problem above, we need to count from 0 to some limit (the total number of combinations). We need to convert each of those numbers to a base 4 number. Then we use each digit of that base 4 number as an index into our input array:

```
int base = input.length;
int digits = 3;

int max = Math.pow(base, digits);

for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    string d = Integer.toString(i, base);
    for (int j=0; j<digits; j++) {
        int index = j < digits.length ? d[j] - '0' : 0; 
        // in[index] is the next result word
    }
    // end of one result set.
}
```